# Joining data from two datatables

Tags: sql, vb.net

I want to show data from two different tables. the 2nd tables consists cild elements for the first table elements. I want to show it like this [image]

but i want the child information to be consecutive i mean right below the brand/listing Informarion. but  in the above im missing something

my VB code

```
  Dim dtListings As New DataTable()
    Dim dtProducts As New DataTable()
    Dim dt3 As New DataTable()
    Dim ds = WebAppBA.GetListingWithProducts()
    Dim ds2 = WebAppBA.GetProductsWithListings()
    dtListings = WebAppBA.GetListingWithProducts().Tables(0)
    dtProducts = WebAppBA.GetProductsWithListings().Tables(0)
    If dtListings IsNot Nothing AndAlso dtListings.Columns.Count > 0 Then
        For Each r As DataColumn In dtListings.Columns
            dt3.Columns.Add(r.ColumnName)
        Next
    End If
    If dtProducts IsNot Nothing AndAlso dtProducts.Columns.Count > 0 Then
        For Each r As DataColumn In dtProducts.Columns
            dt3.Columns.Add(r.ColumnName)
        Next
    End If
    For Each row As DataRow In dtListings.Rows
        dt3.NewRow()
        dt3.ImportRow(row)
        Dim v = dtProducts.[Select]("listingID=" & row("ID")).CopyToDataTable()
        If v IsNot Nothing AndAlso v.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            For Each r As DataRow In v.Rows
                dt3.ImportRow(r)
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

or is there any other way of doing this

Comment: I don't exactly get the meaning of your layouts AT ALL? maybe you want something like a ['nested' table instead](http://www.jqwidgets.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/nested-jquery-grids.png), which would improve readability, and more than likely help you with 'joining data'?

Comment: Could you explain why you don't use the JOIN operator? You could remove all this code with a lot simpler code.

Comment: Yes but with join we can get the result in same row i guess but i want to have the above structure like brand info as a parent row and then the products info for that brands if at all its possible

Comment: All right, but then it is a visualization problem, still I think that JOIN should be used instead of that complex code. But perhaps I am a bit biased because I use grid control that supports a MASTER/DETAIL view of data.

Comment: you need a control which can display what you want. For example infragsitics Ultragrid can visualize what you want or use a treeview but standard MS Treeview won't be pretty due to no columns ...

Comment: Thanks but can we write any query by which we can bring the data as desired as shown above?

Comment: If you do something like what you want, how would you know wich is a listing and wich is a product, as both will be under the same column headers? Also, wich is gonna be, data grid view or [excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481680/printing-child-table-data-for-each-row-in-the-parent-table-in-excel-sheet)

Comment: `with join we can get the result in same row i guess` **Of course**. But then you are able to extract the parts you are interested in from that row and display them accordingly.